# Parition problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, system-installation

Here is my 500 GiB drive, partition scheme:
[image: Partition Scheme]
As you can see there is one unallocated partition that I created beside `dev/sda2` with `80 GiB` volume. `dev/sda2` contains `Windows7 Home Edition` and I'm trying install `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` beside `windows 7`. I have problem with Ubuntu installation because Ubuntu not shown partitions correctly:
[image]

***Note:***

- when I start `GParted` I got this error:

  > Libparted Error : Can't have overlaping partitions.
- `# sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0xa0eb5b3a
  Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors    Size Id Type
  /dev/sda1  *         2048   2081086   2079039 1015.2M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda2         2081094 206050096 203969003   97.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda3       373828832 701510872 327682041  156.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda4       206050097 976769071 770718975  367.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
  /dev/sda5       206050160 373828823 167778664     80G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda6       701528064 976769071 275241008  131.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
  Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
  Partition table entries are not in disk order.
  ```

Comment: The 80 GB freespace between `sda2` and `sda3` is not usable, because the disk uses the MBR partition table format, and you already have three primary partitions plus one extended partition. That unallocated space cannot go into a primary partition because the table is full, and it cannot go into a logical partition because it lies outside the extended partition. Please run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and edit the question to show the output.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the text and paste it into the question, and format is as code. (And it seems to me that `sda3` overlaps `sda4`; this cannot be left like this, and something must be done. There is a clear risk of data loss if the partition table is not corrected.)

Comment: @AlexP I did it. photo removed. thanks. so you think I can't do this without formatting partitions? Another question: I searched for `create partition from unallocated space and moving it out of extended partition` and found that I can use `AOMEI Partition Manager Pro` but after doing steps when try to move that space, I faced `moving partition` greyed out and disabled. I did it because I think if I move that Unallocated space out and format it as `ext3` I can install Ubuntu on it! is it true?